Is there a preference to use Convex-hull reformulation instead of the BigM constraints?
I am trying to work on a scheduling problem based on its polyhedron reformulations. For that, I would like to reformulate a BigM model into its equivalent C-hull formulation. The transforming map is depicted in the following picture:

As an example, suppose there is a simple scheduling model:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad & s_1 + s_2 \\
\text{subject to} \quad & LB \leq s_1 \leq UB \\
\ & LB \leq s_2 \leq UB \\
\ & (s_1 \geq s_2+\alpha) \lor  (s_2 \geq s_1+\beta)\\
                        & s_1, s_2 \geq 0.
\end{align*}
It's linearized as:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad & s_1 + s_2 \\
\text{subject to} \quad & LB \leq s_1 \leq UB \\
\ & LB \leq s_2 \leq UB \\
\ & s_1 - s_2 + (M+\beta)y_1 \leq M \\
\ & s_2 - s_1 + (M+\alpha)y_2 \leq M \\
\ & y_1 + y_2 = 1 \\
                        & s_1, s_2 \geq 0, y_1, y_2 \in \{0,1\}.
\end{align*}
and its C-hull equivalent would be:
\begin{align*}
\text{minimize} \quad & s_1 + s_2 \\
\text{subject to} \quad & s_1 = w_1 + w_2 \\
\ & s_2 = w_3 + w_4 \\
\ & LB \leq s_1 \leq UB \\
\ & LB \leq s_2 \leq UB \\
\ & y_1 + y_2 = 1\\
\ & w_1 - w_3 + \beta y_1 \leq 0\\
\ & w_4 - w_2 + \alpha y_2 \leq 0\\
\ & w_{i^s} - UBy_{i^d} \leq 0 ,\ \forall i \in I \\
                        & s_1, s_2 \geq 0, y_{i^d} \in \{0,1\}, w_{i^s} \geq 0.
\end{align*}
Now, my questions are:

Is it proven that a C-hull formulation always has a better relaxation than a BigM or time-indexed formulation?

Is the time-indexed formulation a kind of C-hull reformulation?

Can we infer a C-hull formulation may lead to reducing the solving process in an MIP?

I have tried to solve a large instance of the above formulation. In that case, it seems the BigM model has a better performance against the C-hull formulation. May it back to the internal mechanism of the modern MIP solvers to deal with BigM formulation rather than whose C-hull model?

What actually is the benefit of the convex hull reformulation if we again need to deal with BigM constraints? Does it really provide a tighter relaxation? If so, why in large instances the BigM formulation seem to solve faster than whose c-hull?


